# Is Document Body Blob field value encoded in Base64 when extracted by Dataloader? Can this encoding be used for insert or update?

Tags: data-loader, dml, blob, base64, data-extract

I want to use Salesforce DataLoader to extract and upload Documents.
However, I don't understand in which format Blob Body values are stored, is it Base64 encoded?

Looks like yes, but why it is not documented anywhere?

Can I use the same Base64 encoding to insert or update Documents as well?

Answer (score 1):

No, I can't use Base64 to insert Documents.
Received Exceeded Max Field size

[image]

Also there is mention in the documentation that VersionData for ContentVersion is automatically converted into Base64, probably the same is valid for Body of Document. Strange, why didn't they mentioned Document Body conversion as well.

> • VersionData - complete file path on your local drive (for uploading
>   documents only). Note: Files are converted to base64 encoding on
>   upload. This action adds approximately 30% to the file size.

[Documentation, page 16 (showing 20/50 in the PDF viewer)](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You can *export* files in base-64 format, but you can only *import* files using files, as documented in [Uploading Attachments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_attachments.htm). Basically, the Body needs to be specified as a file path. The three required fields are Name, ParentId, and Body. For Documents, you need a FolderId, Name, and Body.

Comment: Good catch. I have seen this article before, but it refers Attachments and I need information about Documents. How should I know that what is written for Attachment is also valid for Documents? I would prefer is there was some proper documentation on that.